# Push to origin without having a local .git?

Tags: git, github

I'm developing on a general-use shared server that I ssh into and (1) doesn't have git and (2) I don't have admin rights to install git on my own.  If I want to version my code, I have to pull it back to my local machine using SFTP, commit the changes locals, then push to origin.

Is there a way to add+commit+push newly saved code directly to my git repo without needing a local .git?  I'm the only one working on this project, so no issues of conflicts.

Comment: you can install git in a local folder instead of a system one, and refer to it.

Comment: I fear that @Jepessen is right and the only way out is to install Git somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Install Git on a local folder in your remote server. It's not difficult and if you add the location in your $PATH you can use it as usual without inserting the entire path when using it.
- You can create a script in you remote machine that perform the work for you. The script should copy using scp your project folder into your local machine, connect through ssh to your local machine and perform git commands automatically.

In the second case you can use in your bash script something like that

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p remoteuser ssh -X -l -t localuser@localmachine << EOF
cd your/project/path
git commit -a -m "Automated commit"
git push origin
EOF
```

and call it from remote machine.

The script should work if there are no conflicts and working/pushing current branch.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
You can mount the root of the repository on your server into a local directory, then create a local .git repo into the mounted dir, add your remote server and finally push all.

With this way the git local repo is created into the server (not locally).
To mount use sshfs

```
mkdir ~/mnt
sshfs username@server_ip:path_to_root_of_repo ~/mnt
chmod +x ~/mnt
```